# VBA GetPivotData

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to resolve an issue where I have a simple pivot table with one row called "Autonumber" and other columns called Q1Data, Q2Data, etc. I want to do some simple processing of the data by going through each column, removing anything with a value of 20, then averaging each column before going to the next row. I want to use GetPivotData to select my entire dataset (or each column) but cannot seem to get it to work. Can someone help? Here is the code and it is giving me a run-time error 1004 (Application defined or object defined error) on the debug.print statement.

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim LastRowSharepoint As Integer
Dim LastColumnSharepoint As Integer
Dim AvgRowCount As Integer
Dim TotalVal As Integer
Dim AvgVal As Single
Dim TempVar() As Variant

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

LastRowSharepoint = pt.RowRange.Count
LastColumnSharepoint = pt.ColumnRange.Count

For a = 1 To LastColumnSharepoint
    For b = 1 To LastRowSharepoint
        Debug.Print pt.GetPivotData("AutoNumber", "Q1Data")
        If TempVar(b, a) <> "20" Then
            AvgRowCount = AvgRowCount + 1
            TotalVal = TotalVal + SharepointTable.Range(b, a)
        End If
    Next b
    AvgVal = TotalVal / AvgRowCount
Next a

End Sub
```

Comment: It's erroring because ```GetPivotData``` returns a range, you can't print objects. If you were to put ```.address``` after that it would print the range address property as an example.

Comment: Is there a way I can capture the entire range to use later? For example, if I were to say TempVar(some 2D list size)=pt.GetPivotData("AutoNumber", "Q1Data" would that work? What would be the right way of harvesting that range data into a 2D list (that can change in size if the pt is changed) that I can use?

Comment: `GetPivotData` gives you the range, as @Warcupine mentioned. Just assign it to a variable, as in `Dim q1data As Range; Set q1data = pt.GetPivotData("AutoNumber", "Q1Data")`. The range object can be converted into a 2D list if you need it in that form, of just iterate over the range of cells.

Comment: @PeterT I just tried that as well but unfortunately I'm, still getting the same error... I am unsure if my table is set up incorrectly or what their issue is. Sorry if I am doing something dumb, I'm not used to PivotTable manipulation. I'm also new to stack overflow...  `Dim QData As Range;
Dim pt As PivotTable;
Dim LastRowSharepoint As Integer;
Dim LastColumnSharepoint As Integer;

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1);

For a = 1 To LastColumnSharepoint;
    For b = 1 To LastRowSharepoint;
        Set QData = pt.GetPivotData("AutoNumber", "Q1Data")`